# how to convert any number of list to between 0 and 1

Tags: c#

For example :

I have the number of list like below : {12,23,34,45,65} to change between 0 and 1 like 
{0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}. Does any body know some algorithm?

Comment: What you mean to change ? Please describe in more details what you need to do.

Comment: the minimum (12) is 0? Why isn't the maximum (65) 1?

Comment: How do you determine 65 maps to 0.8?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail - how do you want the resulting list distributed? Is 65 the highest number so that 65 gets mapped to 1?

Comment: -1 'cause the question is unintellegible(<- dows this word exist in english?)

Comment: yeah yeah 65 gets mapped to 1 actually not exactly 1 near by 1 like 0.99 something like. Also minimum gets mapped to 0. I wanted to compare these results with Next.double().

Comment: Just for context : this is known as 'normalization' for data processing; changing the data range to 0..1 from the real min..max values, while keeping the proportional differences between data.

Comment: This question is indeed sounds stupid but I voted it up because the same question popped out of my head too. I didn't know the words "normalization" and "proportional differences". Without these it's quite hard to describe/search the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
double max = 1.0 * oldList.Max();
var newList = oldList.Select(x => x / max);
```

If you want the lowest number to map to 0 then you'll need something like this:

```
double min = 1.0 * oldList.Min();
double max = 1.0 * oldList.Max();
var newList = oldList.Select(x => (x - min) / (max - min));
```

Comment: first element (=12) results in .18 with this solution. See my solution - you have to look for the minimum, too.

Comment: @tanascius: Was just editing to do that, although the original question wasn't really clear about the requirements. The OP has since added a comment confirming that this is the behaviour that they want.

Comment: @user347918: if this answer is what you were looking for, than you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 6):

A very easy and efficient way to do this is to do a logit transformation. Logit formula is:

```
y = ln (x / (1 - x))
```

where `y` is a number between 0 and 1, following the binary distribution. Also, it is great because `y` can be zero or negative.

So let's do the way around it, so we can transform our data (`y`) into binominal distribution (infinite numbers constricted between 0 and 1).

```
y = ln (x / (1 - x))
exp(y) = exp (ln(x / (1 - x)) # to get rid of ln() we can make the exp() on both sides
exp(y) = x / (1 - x)          # exponential rule: exp(ln(z)) = z

x = exp(y) * (1 - x)
x = exp(y) - x * exp(y)
x + x * exp(y) = exp(y)
x (1 + exp(y) = exp(y)

x = exp(y)/(1 + exp(y))
```

This is WAY easier and simpler than the other suggestions!
I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the max number in the sequence.
2. Divide all the numbers by the max
   number

Comment: first element (=12) results in .18 with this solution. See my solution - you have to look for the minimum, too.

Comment: yeap now i understand what should i do I really appreciate you guys

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

- find maximum and minimum
- divide each (element - minimum) by (maximum - minimum)

*Note:* This will map the maximum to 1.0 ... which however is not the case in your example.

*Edit:*

```
var min = list.First();    // assumes a sorted list, else use Min()
var max = list.Last();     // assumes a sorted list, else use Max()
double difference = max - min;
var newList = list.Select( i => Math.Round( (i - min ) / difference, 1 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

expecting you want the highest to be 1.0 and the lowest value to be 0.0 and your array is in order from lowest to highest:

```
int lowest = myArray[0];
int highest = myArray[myArray.Length-1];
int diff = highest - lowest;

foreach (int item in myArray)
    Console.WriteLine = (float)(item - lowest) / diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the lowest to map to 0, and the highest to map to 1, then the following will achieve this:

```
var input = new double[] { 12, 23, 34, 45, 65 };

var outputList = input.ToList().Select(i => (i - input.Min()) / (input.Max() - input.Min()));

foreach (var i in outputList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```